# Data synchronization between android and PC?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a PC application in java to do synchronization of data between PC and android. I want to know the best way to do it. My android app has a database and I want to  sync it with a PC application. Can anyone help me with a way to do it?

Comment: Hi Anu.. I need your email id

Comment: @Rakshi Hi my mail id: anurgp@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it would be easy to write a server program listening on a local port on PC, and then a simple client program on Android, connecting to the server program, and sync data using plain socket. this requires the server&client programs are in the same subnet(like through wifi).

Comment: is it possible to do the sync through the USB connection?

Comment: hope the information is relevant to my problem.. As a beginner in java and android I have confusions in doing it.. thank you for your time..

Comment: Since you are a new member on SO, I think I have responsibility to remind you that if an answer answers your question, you should tick it on the left:)

Comment: yes I know that.. let me try ur suggestions and will do that if I succeed.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the open source project, OpenMobster's Sync service. You can do the following sync operations

- two-way
- one-way client
- one-way device
- bootup

Besides that, all modifications are automatically tracked and synced with the Cloud. You can have your app offline when network connection is down. It will track any changes and automatically in the background synchronize it with the cloud when the connection returns.

It also supports sync across multiple devices like iCloud does.

In your case,

You would develop a Java Channel and expose the data from the PC via the Sync Channel. On the Android side you will be able to access this data via a Sync API. All your changes are auto tracked and synchronized in both directions.

You do not have to deal with developing a Socket Server or doing the low-level sync stuff yourself. You stay at a high level dealing with data

Here is a link to the open source project: http://openmobster.googlecode.com

Here is a tutorial to understand some of its workings: http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/AndroidSyncApp

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mobeelizer](http://mobeelizer.com/) for that. Mobeelizer is cloud synchronization service. There are SDK's for Java and separated for Android. To solve you problem you can synchronize your PC database with Mobeelizer cloud and then sync Android database also with the cloud.

In Mobeelizer there is a lot of stuff for you, you can for example notify you Android app that new data is available, you can use permissions or even prepare your own conflict resolving - remember when a few users can modify same data conflict may occures and you have to resolve them.

You can find tutorials for Java:
[here](http://docs.mobeelizer.com/display/doc/Java+Simple+Tutorial)
and for Android : 
[here](http://docs.mobeelizer.com/display/doc/Android+Advanced+Tutorial)

Enjoy.